# serviceStack and protobuff

Tags: servicestack, protobuff.net

This is a type I define

```
public class NewPropVideoResponse
{
    [DataMember(Order = 1)]
    public int VideoId { get; set; }
}
```

This is the type I want to return

```
NewPropVideoResponse[]
```

How do I use protobuff serialization?

Answer (score 0):

Please read the ServiceStack docs on how to register the [ProtoBuf Format](http://docs.servicestack.net/protobuf-format). Once the format is registered, if you call your Service using the [ProtoBufServiceClient](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.ProtoBuf/ProtoBufServiceClient.cs), the client will request the Response to be returned in `application/x-protobuf` and ServiceStack will respond in kind returning the response serialized in the ProtoBuf format.